# Error al cargar Turbolinks "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Turbolinks' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Acabo de instalar los Turbolinks en mi proyecto de Rails para que trabaje junto con React.

Lo he instalado mediante yarn.

Cuando lo inicializo:

```
var Turbolinks = require('turbolinks');
window.Turbolinks = Turbolinks;
Turbolinks.start();
```

Me devuelve un error en consola que evitar que cargue mi componente, si no está siendo renderizado en servidor:

```
turbolinks.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Turbolinks' of undefined
    at turbolinks.js:21
    at turbolinks.js:35
    at turbolinks.js:36
```

¿Alguien puede iluminarme?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `window` no está definido en tu entorno de ejecucion de JS, el objeto `window`es un objeto disponible en Javascript cuando el código se ejecuta en un navegador o webview, pero en tu caso no parece que estés ejecutandolo en un navegador. No tengo muy claro cómo interactúa RoR con React, pero yo probaría a usarlo sin la línea: `window.Turbolinks = Turbolinks;`

Comment: Si! Lo solucioné quitando el window, lo va a buscar a la dependencia y no necesita meterlo en window. Muchas gracias :)